# How can light sensor be enabled for control brightness and keyboard back-light automatically?

Tags: 12.04, brightness, vaio, sony, backlight

I have A Sony VAIO laptop F-series () Nvidia and it has **light sensor**. When I was using Windows, this light sensor controlled *the brightness and the keyboard backlight automatically* due to the surroundings state.

But when using Ubuntu 12.04, it only controls the backlight without automatically adjusting the brightness.

How can I enable light sensor to automatically adjustment the LCD brightness without losing the keyboard backlight adjustment due to surrounding state?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no automatic method that I am aware of built into Ubuntu. However, take a look at [lightum](http://pof.eslack.org/2011/12/04/lightum-auto-adjust-keyboard-brightness-on-macbook/)

It works fine on my mac but I have my lgiht senser in `/sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/light`

You can check out the [code](https://github.com/poliva/lightum) and make the modifications or use it to write your own app.

The principal is sound, and I have seen other scripts do the same thing. If you don't want to tackle lightum try [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/mactel-linux-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00270.html) or take a look at [this mac info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro6-2/Precise#Keyboard).

I know you have a sony but the process should be the same, read the sensor, set some values to a file in /sys/

Comment: i go to /sys/devices/platform/ and can't find the file 'light' 

there is a folder called Sony-laptop but i can't find where it is ??

Comment: Try `/sys/class/backlight/sony/brightness` Of course knowing your exact model would help a lot.

Comment: found  [this](http://medjaimod.com/enable-ambient-light-sensor-ubuntu-11-04-sony-vaio/) googling, it's a bit old, but it's a start.

Comment: there is two folder in that path : "acpi_video0" and "acpi_video1" >>> my model is VPCF236FM

Comment: `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

Comment: let me know what is there. [from here](http://medjaimod.com/enable-ambient-light-sensor-ubuntu-11-04-sony-vaio/)

Comment: cat command output is : 15

Comment: Ok now, check it again but in a different room, or with different lights on or something. We are trying to make sure that '15' is the light sensor, as it seems a bit of an odd spot to put it in.